# How can we import python file form one directory to another directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import

I have a framework structure like

```
Stopper
    /module1
        file1.py
        file2.py
        __init__.py
    /module2
        file3.py
        file4.py
        __init__.py
runner.py
files.py
__init__.py
```

I want to import class or functions from `file3.py` to `file2.py`, as they are different directory. 
Please let me know how to handle this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)